# error: 'else' without a previous if

Tags: c

I am getting a `error: 'else' without a previous if` when i'm compiling using gcc on this bit of code:

```
while(fgets(line, 50, fr) != NULL)
{
    if(count == 0)
    {
        fileOpen1 = "pro1.pifz";
    }
    else
    {
        fileOpen2 = "pro2.pifz";
    }
    else
    {
        fileOpen2 = "pro3.pifz";
    }   
    count++;
    printf("%s", line);
    printf("%s", fileOpen1);
    printf("%s", fileOpen2);
    printf("%s", fileOpen3);
}
fclose(fr);
```

The error come when i add the second `else` function. Is there a simple way of fixing this error?
Many thanks

Comment: `if` and `else` cover **all** possibilities. What could a second `else` achieve?

Comment: Use `else if` instead of second `else`

Comment: perhaps `else if (count == 1)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not use two else statements one after another in if statement. The if statement may have only one else statement.

```
else
{
    fileOpen2 = "pro2.pifz";
}
else
{
    fileOpen2 
}
```

You could write for example instead

```
else if ( /* some condition */ )
{
    fileOpen2 = "pro2.pifz";
}
else
{
    fileOpen2 
}
```